# Reading custom attributes

Tags: c#, attributes, system.reflection

In my following code snippet, I'm not able to understand as to why "customAttribute" value for property "XX" is always null.It works fine for property "X" though.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] props = myInp.GetProperties();
foreach (var prop in props)
{
  if (prop.Name == "XX")
  {
    var customAttribute = prop.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(CustomAttribute)) as CustomAttribute; //This is always null for XX                      
     }
}


    public class MyClass
    {

    [CustomAttribute(MyProp1 = true, MyProp2="test")]
    public bool X{ get ; set;}, 

    [CustomAttribute(MyProp1 = true)]   
    public MyEnum XX{ get ; set;}

    }


    public enum MyEnum
        {
            ABC = 0,
            XYZ = 1
        }


    public class CustomAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public bool MyProp1 { get; set; }
            public string MyProp2 { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: I checked your code and it is working fine. There is a small syntax issue after the public bool X property, which has a ',' at the end of that line. Can you tell me what is myInp?

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine for me:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myClassProps = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties();

        foreach (var prop in myClassProps.Where(p => p.Name == nameof(MyClass.XX)))
        {
            var attribs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CustomAttribute), false);

            if (attribs.Length > 0)
            {
                var customAttrib = attribs[0] as CustomAttribute;

                //Do Something with it here
            }
        }
    }
}

public enum MyEnum
{
    ABC = 0,
    XYZ = 1
}


public class CustomAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool MyProp1 { get; set; }
    public string MyProp2 { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    [Custom(MyProp1 = true, MyProp2 = "test")]
    public bool X { get; set; } 

    [Custom(MyProp1 = true)]
    public MyEnum XX { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not sure where you get the `PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute`, I couldn't find that member in `PropertyInfo`.